# Array's elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

- What am I trying to do:
  Given an array of numbers, for example: `["1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3"]`,
  I want to find the element that is **most repeated** in the array.
  But, I also want to know if there is more than 1 element that satisfies the requirement, and what are those elements.
- I couldn't think of any idea on how to start with this yet...

Comment: See [Get the element with the highest occurrence in an array](/a/38940041/4642212). Get familiar with [how to access and process objects, arrays, or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212), and use the static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods). Also, what you’re looking for is called the [mode](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28statistics%29).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is an approach using `Array.reduce()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

- First I determine for each unique value in the array how many times it does occur, by returning an object like `{"1": 3, "2": 3, "3": 1}`
- Then I determine which are the values occurred most of the times
  in the array, by returning an object like `{"count": 3, "values": ["1", "2"]}`

```js
const data = ["1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3"];

//returns the number of time each unique value occurs in the array
const counts = data.reduce( (counts, item) => {
  if(item in counts)
    counts[item] += 1;
  else
    counts[item] = 1;
  return counts;
}, {});

console.log(counts);
/*
{
  "1": 3,
  "2": 3,
  "3": 1
}
*/

//returns which values and how many times occur the most 
const max = Object.entries(counts)
  .reduce((max, [value, count])=> {
      if(count < max.count)
        return max;
      if(count == max.count){
        max.values.push(value);
        return max;
      }
      return {count: count, values: [value]};
    },{count: 0, values: []});

console.log(max);
/*
{
  "count": 3,
  "values": [
    "1",
    "2"
  ]
}
*/
```